# issue in bus seat layout in android

Tags: android, bus, ticket-system

i want to create bus ticket booking layout in my app . i created layout but seat arrangement not came proper. below is image . i just want to seat layout proper other element is proper
[image: in this seat layout not proper i want to seat layout same as paytm bus ticket layout]

seat_selection_screen.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/header"
        layout="@layout/common_header_with_sub_title" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/busDeckSelectionLayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="45.0dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/busDeckSelectionButtons"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="#ffeeeeee" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/lowerDeck"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:background="@drawable/left_button"
                android:text="@string/lower"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12.0sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/upperDeck"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/lowerDeck"
                android:background="@drawable/right_button"
                android:text="@string/upper"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12.0sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/busDeckSelectionMargin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.0dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/busDeckSelectionLayout"
        android:background="#ffdddddd" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/seatSelectionHeader"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/busDeckSelectionMargin" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/seatsLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
            android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/seatsSelectedText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:text="@string/seats_selected"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="12.0sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/seatsSelected"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/seatsSelectedText"
                android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="14.0sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/fareLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="40.0dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/seatsLayout"
            android:background="@layout/fare_seat_selection_background" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/rsText"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dip"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
                android:text="@string/rupees"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18.0sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/fare"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10.0dip"
                android:layout_marginRight="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="18.0sp" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/seatSelectionHeaderMargin"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1.0dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seatSelectionHeader"
        android:background="#ffdddddd" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/seatLayoutScroll"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomBarSeatSelection"
        android:layout_below="@+id/seatSelectionHeaderMargin"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/scrollableLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/seatLegendLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5.0dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="5.0dip" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/availableImageLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/availableImage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
                        android:rotation="90.0"
                        android:src="@drawable/seat_layout_tab_nor_avl" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/availableText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/availableImage"
                        android:text="@string/available"
                        android:textSize="12.0sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/bookedImageLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/availableImageLayout" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/bookedImage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
                        android:rotation="90.0"
                        android:src="@drawable/seat_layout_tab_nor_bkd" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/bookedText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bookedImage"
                        android:text="@string/booked"
                        android:textSize="12.0sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/selectedImageLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bookedImageLayout" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/selectedImage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
                        android:rotation="90.0"
                        android:src="@drawable/seat_layout_tab_nor_std" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/selectedText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/selectedImage"
                        android:text="@string/selected"
                        android:textSize="12.0sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/ladiesImageLayout"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/selectedImageLayout">

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/ladiesImage"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="10.0dip"
                        android:rotation="90.0"
                        android:src="@drawable/seat_layout_tab_nor_lad_avl" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/ladiesText"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5.0dip"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ladiesImage"
                        android:text="@string/ladies"
                        android:textSize="12.0sp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/seatLayoutLowerMain"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_below="@+id/seatLegendLayout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
                android:background="@layout/seat_layout_border"
                android:paddingBottom="5.0dp"
                android:paddingRight="5.0dp" >

                <GridView
                    android:id="@+id/gridView1"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/driver"
                    android:layout_margin="4dp"
                    android:columnWidth="100dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:numColumns="4"
                    android:stretchMode="columnWidth" >
                </GridView>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/driver"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/gridView1"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20.0dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5.0dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/steering_icon"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/seatLayoutUpper"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/seatLegendLayout"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="10.0dip"
                android:background="@layout/seat_layout_border"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomBarSeatSelection"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="49.0dip"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/white" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/doneButton"
            android:layout_width="160.0dip"
            android:layout_height="48.0dip"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_red_btn"
            android:text="@string/done"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18.0sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/cancelButton"
            android:layout_width="160.0dip"
            android:layout_height="48.0dip"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="1.0dip"
            android:background="@drawable/selector_black_btn"
            android:text="@string/goBack"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="18.0sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

[image: i want this type of layout for seat]

Comment: I suggest u to use GridView

Comment: i already used gridview

Comment: You mean you want to fix it as you have shown in Second Screen Shot Right ?

Comment: yes...i want to layout same as 2nd screenshot